# Running JAX on CPU

Tags: python, cpu, jax

I have installed JAX for TPU on wsl but it didnt work. Therefore, I just want to use JAX on my CPU but it automatically tries to run on the TPU. Is it possible to disable this or uninstall everything for TPU usage?

Ive tried uninstalling and re-installing jax module using pip but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

JAX will only attempt to run on TPU when the `libtpu` package is available. If you don't want JAX to target TPUs, you can remove it:

```py
pip uninstall libtpu-nightly
```

If for some reason you'd like to use CPU device by default in a system where libtpu is installed, you can do so by setting `jax_default_device` to the CPU device:

```py
import jax
jax.config.update('jax_default_device', jax.devices('cpu')[0])
```